# Openfiledialog error for selecting DBF files

Tags: c#, ado.net

Help. on this line fails: adapter.Fill(ds);  // ERROR Check the name is invalid, it does not contain invalid characters or punctuation and not too long.

```
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Выбрать файл";
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory ="C:\\";        
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "dbf файлы (*.dbf)|*.dbf";            
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;           
        openFileD`ial`og1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";


         if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
string fullPathname = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fullPathname);
                    string open_b = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fi.Directory + ";Extended Properties=dBase 5.0;Mode=Read|Write|Share Deny None;Persist Security Info=True";
                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
                    con.ConnectionString = open_b;
                    con.Open();



                 string vibor_t = "Select * From '" + fi.Name + "'";
                //string vibor_t = "Select * From '" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name) + "'";

                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(vibor_t, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);  // ERROR
                con.Close();
                this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: fi.Directory is not a valid data source.  Use openFileDialog1.FileName instead.

Answer (score 0):

You got to remove extension from fi.Name, and remove single qotes, something like this :

```
string vibor_t = "Select * From " + Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension(fi.Name);
```